# No alert on click

Tags: jquery

I have a simple problem i guess.

If i click on a div i want a message to appear.

my code in my body for the div is.

```
<div id="addtag" style="cursor: pointer;">
   <b>
   add tag
   </b>
</div>
```

if i click on this div i want a simple alert box, so i have in my head:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#addtag').click(function() 
    {
        alert("hello world");
    });
</script>
```

But i dont get any message what have i done wrong?

Comment: Are you [**Ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? Go!

Comment: @MelanciaUK its because fiddle automatically wrap your code inside `document.ready`.

Comment: I've even deleted my comment after realizing that. Hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse not

```
$(function(){
    $('#addtag').click(function() 
    {
        alert("hello world");
    });
});
```

Comment: You too? Now there's two of us :D

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a [DOM-ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and I'll bet your code is fine:

```
$(function () {
    $('#addtag').click(function() 
    {
        alert("hello world");
    });
});
```

The problem is that you try to attach an event-listener to the element, before the element is actually in the DOM.

Another option, if you don't want to use a DOM-ready callback, would be to move your script-tag to the very bottom of your HTML-body, just before the closing `</body>`. That way you know that when the code is executed, the element will be available in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addtag').click(function() 
{
    alert("hello world");
});
}};
```

use with DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addtag').click(function() 
    {
        alert("hello world");
    });
 });
</script>
```

Here you need to initialize the click function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addtag').bind('click',function(){
    //alert('hi');
    });
  });
```